# I need a regex for the following combination

Tags: regex, pcre

```
mission_id: a498094578a
mission_id: a493453456
mission_id: 498343454a
mission_id: 34534535345
```

From the above 4 mission_id's I need your help in writing a regex pattern which covers all the four mission_id but need to select only the numbers.

So one the first one - need to exempt 'a' and only the numbers.

Comment: You can straight-up just look for `\d+`............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mission_id:\s*\w?(\d*)\w?
```

That should work; maybe add any flags you need for parsing multiline text or whatever.

www.regexr.com is a great resource for trying out RegExps